# Strange behavior in SQL with CASE WHEN EXIST in subquery (MySQL 5.5)

Tags: mysql, subquery, case, exists

I've got a shop with items and itemgroups.

I also got some additional items, from which one should randomly be selected to present it in the cart overview, if that one is not present in the cart allready.

There can be items linked to the items group as well. If there is no item linked to the items in the cart i want one of them, that is not allready inside the cart to be randomly selected

I save relations between items inside table **item2item**:

```
itemid INT 
additional_item_id INT
```

I save relations between groups and items in table **group2item**

```
groupid INT
additional_item_id INT
```

To make it a little more simple let's assume my **item** table looks like this:

```
itemid INT
name VARCHAR(100)
```

Here is what i tried to get an additional item:

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    items a
WHERE 
    (a.itemid) = (
            # if we have any additional items linked to the item get one of em randomly, that is not inside of a cart
            SELECT 
                CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                                    SELECT 
                                        b.additional_item_id 
                                    FROM 
                                        item2item b 
                                    WHERE 
                                        b.additional_item_id NOT IN (10) 
                                        AND b.itemid IN (10)
                                ) 
                        THEN (
                                SELECT 
                                        c.additional_item_id 
                                    FROM 
                                        item2item c 
                                    WHERE 
                                        c.additional_item_id NOT IN (10) 
                                        AND b.itemid IN (10)
                                    ORDER BY 
                                        RAND() 
                                    LIMIT 1
                        # else if we have additional items linked to the items group get one of em randomly, that is not inside of a cart
                        ) ELSE (
                                    (
                                        SELECT 
                                            d.additional_item_id 
                                        FROM 
                                            group2item d 
                                        WHERE 
                                            d.additional_item_id NOT IN (10) 
                                        AND 
                                            d.groupid IN (1) 
                                        ORDER BY RAND() 
                                        LIMIT 1
                                    )
                        ) 
                    END as selecteditemid 
            )
```

Anyone can explain to me, why i get different amounts of rows with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking why you might get different numbers of rows.  Here are some thoughts:

- `items.itemid` is not unique, so the duplicates are coming from multiple matches.
- The `else` clause is executed and the `where` clause filters out all rows.
- The `else` clause is executed and `group2item.additional_item_id` matches no `items.itemid`.

I speculate that it might be possible that when the first condition in the `case` statement is executed, the data might change between the `when` and `then`.

If you are looking for a fix to this, then move the subqueries to the `from` clause and put simpler logic in the `where`.

Comment: items.itemid is primary key.

I've got entries in both item2item and group2item which met the specified values.

While testing my sql i am actually workign with static values and still get different amounts of values...

Could you give an example on how to use the subqueries inside the from clause?

Thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: btw. (a.itemid) = (subquery) <- this subquery always produces exactly one id